# These are my kind of people meaning?

Tags: meaning

While his car is stuck in traffic. Cars HONK and people YELL...

Anger says:

"These are my kind of people!"

What does this actually mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common expression indicating that the speaker feels comfortable around the referenced type of person because he or she identifies with their behavior.

While many people would feel uncomfortable in a situation where people are yelling and honking in frustration, the speaker considers himself a high-conflict person, who is comfortable yelling at strangers in traffic and being yelled at in turn. Perhaps he has been uncomfortable spending time with low-conflict people and finds the yelling refreshing.

There is a stereotype that people in New York yell and curse at each other grumpily with little provocation, which often makes visitors uncomfortable.  On the other hand, someone from New York may find the more polite way people outside the city interact unusual and uncomfortable.  This speaker is indicating that what may appear to be a tense situation to the listener is refreshing to him.  These apparently rude people are "his type" because they are behaving as he would.

Comment: The character in question here is "Anger" from Pixar's "Inside Out" film.  He embodies the emotion Anger, so of course he is going to enjoy it when others express his emotion.  It shows that those people or being controlled by the same anger avatar, so he is pleased and shows kinship towards his "team"